# Subaru Forester - petrol coming out unlit in bursts out exhaust. Ideas on what could cause it?

Tags: engine, subaru, electronic-control-module, misfire, rich

I've got a Subaru Forester '02 2.5L that I push kind of hard off road on New Zealand beaches.

I had a near dead battery recently so bought a new one but on replacing it I must have wiped the ECU because it has no clue how to run the engine now.

It runs (just) but is super rich, a strong smell of unburnt petrol and is in a constant state of almost stalling. If I blip the accelerator it will either kill the engine or possibly backfire/misfire.

[image]

Watch the video, it's some pretty strange stuff
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PooAiOYusFE

Here's what I know is wrong with it:

- 0₂ sensor broken (I believe it's rear but haven't confirmed )

And what I have tried:

- Tried doing another ECU reset, slightly better results but still same issues
- Replaced the MAP sensor with another used one (Hitachi boost sensor PS60-01) , no difference
- Listened/felt for vacuum leaks, didn't do a rigorous job by any means but couldn't find anything obvious

Anyone seen anything like this and have ideas on what to do next?

Comment: I can’t see a link to your video.  I had to search for it on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a faulty spark plug, ignition lead to the plug, or a faulty ignition coil.

If you are not getting a spark at one of the plugs, you will get unburnt fuel coming out of the exhaust and it would be running like that on 3 cylinders.

Take the plugs out one at a time to find the one that looks wet with fuel.  Then work back from there.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a good diagnosis, considering how the fuel is really coming out in spurts and the engine is wobbling like crazy

Answer (score 1):

Super simple, but I reset the error codes with a little bluetooth OBDII scanner and the engine has come right!

Answer (score 0):

These EJ25 motors are [prone to head gasket leaks](https://oards.com/subaru-head-gasket-problems/). Judging by the white smoke, the first thing I would do is a leak down test. I have a strong suspicion you're burning coolant, which could also be the cause of the misfire.

> The main problem years are 1996 through 2004. The most common engine to have head gasket failures is the naturally aspirated (non turbo) Subaru 2.5 L four cylinder engine, commonly known as the EJ25 motor.

The rich smell is probably caused by the bad O2 sensor. Your car should have two: one near the Y bend at the end of the exhaust manifold, and one further down the exhaust system near the catalytic converter.